# finding the mode and multi mode of a given data set

Tags: python, dictionary, mode

my goal is to find the mode  If you have two or more numbers occurring the same number of times then the mode is all those numbers.

my approach was to put the data into a dictionary and grab the key or key(s) with the max value

#codebelow

```
data=[3 , 4 , 3 ,4 , 4,3,1,1]

dict= {}
for number in data:
    if number in dict:
        dict[number] +=1
        
    else:
        dict[number] = 1

print(dict.keys() , dict.values() )
```

#output Below

`dict_keys([1, 3, 4]) dict_values([2, 3, 3])`

how do i access key(s) with greatest value?

Comment: Just a remark to make sure I understand the problem correctly: That's not what "mode" is in statistics. It's what "frequency" or "count" is.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverFlow. Read [ask-question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). And it would save the others time if you could provide details i.e. What's the desired output. i.e. some demo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python's `collections` Module brings the `Counter` class, which does exactly this in a single line of code.

Comment: Thanks for the input, worked like a charm once I familiarized myself with the Counter class.